# Limiting FCKEditor to only one input format in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, fckeditor

I have two input formats on my Drupal installation, namely: 'html' and 'plain text'. I want to have the FCKEditor ONLY appear if html is selected, but not if plain text is chosen. Is this possible?

I know this was possibl with TinyMCE, but I can't figure out how to do it with FCK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module. It supports FCK and many others.

Comment: True, altho I actually just needed to know where to set FCK to one content type. I found its in the normal settings of FCK and that solved my problem.